# How to draw lineGraph using CorePlot framework in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, core-plot, linegraph, bar-chart

I have downloaded `Core-Plot Header 9.0`and added in my new Project. I am very new to draw graphs and using Core-Plot framework. I have downloaded sample project `CPTTestApp-iPhone` from core-plot sample projects. I opened this project it is contains `CorePlot-Cocoa Touch.xcodeproj` If i tried to run this project from XCode4.2 automatically XCode3.2.4 App opens. I just copied the source code from `CPTTestAppScatterPlotController.h` and pasted in my new project. The `CPTTestAppScatterPlotController.h` having a nib file, but i dont ve any nib files for this and also i want to do it programmatically. So, i just changed these lines from `CPTTestAppScatterPlotController.h` in my project as likes below code,

```
graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    CPTTheme *theme = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTDarkGradientTheme];
    [graph applyTheme:theme];

    CPTGraphHostingView *hostingView = [[CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    hostingView.hostedGraph = graph;
    hostingView.collapsesLayers = NO;
    //hostingView.collapsesLayers = YES; // Setting to YES reduces GPU memory usage, but can slow drawing/scrolling
    [self.view addSubview:hostingView];
```

But, the all functionalities i didn't change from `CPTTestAppScatterPlotController.h`. Still the project not running and it shows `Build Succeeded`. My doubt is i need to import `CorePlot-Cocoa Touch.xcodeproj` in my new project? and how can i run my project? Please help me to run my project. I searched a lot in google and all are suggested this project for beginners `CPTTestApp-iPhone`. Am also trying this project only. Thanks in advance. Waiting for your great solutions. This is the error occur when i'm running the project `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSDecimalNumber cgFloatValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all. I have solved this problem. I just forgot to add `-ObjC -all_load` in mu project Target Build settings. Pelase follow below steps to avoid my problem,

```
1. Copy the CorePlotHeaders to your Xcode project

2. Copy libCorePlotCocoaTouch.a to your Xcode project

3. Add to Other Linker Flags in your target build settings:

-ObjC -all_load
```

Thanks.